# stop all animations in a iframe page

Tags: javascript, css, animation, iframe, browser

Is it possible to stop/resume all animations in a iframe page?

No matter the animations created by js,css3,canvas,create.js,gsap and so on.

I think document.hidden or document.visibilityState can do things like this.

They are read-only,so I tried to dispatch a customer `visibilitychange` event like this:

`iframeDoc.addEventListener('visibilitychange', visibilityChanged,false);`

But it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me is it possible to stop/resume all animations in frame page?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You can change the visibility or display of the iframe Element itself, if it's on a page you created or the same domain. If the content was not created by you that's in the iframe you can't control that without CORS access.

Comment: Thanks.I just want to stop/resume all animations in iframe(is not created by me).I think it's maybe impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally people use setInterval(timeinms,animationfunction) for canvas animation so if you add a variable which change(toggles) between two values such as 0 and 1 every time event occurs and then use if(var=value1){ setInterval( , ) } then the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you parth718.I know what do you mean.But the animation in the iframe page is unknown to me,and the way they made are different.I want to find a common way to do the work.

Comment: I searched iframe animations they use the same way i.e. setTimeout or  setInterval  method to animate. Can you give a sample of your js code used for animations.